# c++ polymorphism and list

Tags: c++, list, polymorphism

```
struct struct_unit{};
struct struct_unit_rotable : struct_unit {};

std::list <struct_unit> unitsList;



struct_unit *su=new struct_unit_rotable;
unitsList.push_front(*su);
```

then i have 2 draw methods:

```
void drawUnit(struct_unit &su);
void drawUnit(struct_unit_rotable &su);
```

when i call `drawUnit(unitsList.front());` --- the WRONG nonrotable draw method is called

how to correctly insert 
`struct_unit_rotable` type into `list` so the `unitsList.front()` will return type `struct_unit_rotable`?

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand polymorphism. The idea of polymorphism is to allow derived classes to provide implementations for methods declared `virtual` in a base class, but use *pointer or reference* to base class to access that implementation (if you use the objects directly, they will get sliced, see David's answer). In your case, there are no such declarations and hence no polymorphism.

To invoke polymorphism you would need

```
struct unit
{
  virtual void draw();
  virtual ~unit();      // important
};
struct unit_rotatable   // did you really mean 'rotable'?
 : unit
{
  virtual void draw();         // 'virtual' needed only for another level of polymorphism
  virtual ~unit_rotatable();
}
```

and invoke them via

```
std::list <std::unique_ptr<unit>> unitsList;      // we need pointer (or reference) to base
unitList.emplace_front(new unit_rotatable);
unitList.front()->draw();                         // calls unit_rotatable::draw()
```

I used `unique_ptr` to ensure the automatic de-allocation of the objects at the destruction of `unitsList`.

Comment: It looks corret, but you're leaking memory. Also, any virtual class should have a virtial destructor (so that `delete base_ptr;` destructs any polymorphic object correctly).

Answer (score 1):

Your list will contain objects of type struct_unit. If you pass it objects of type struct_unit_rotable they will get [sliced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)

Even if you use pointers only void drawUnit(struct_unit *su) will get called, you need to put the polymorphism into the structures as [Walter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23241982/259) has shown

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an odd use of polymorphism.
A better way would be a `virtual drawUnit()` in `struct_unit` that will be overridden in `struct_unit_rotable`.

I do not have the standard at hand but I am sure that there is no proper way without casting to detect the most appropriate method as for the vector content it is of type `struct_unit`.

See here for a related issue: [Matching an overloaded function to its polymorphic argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897662/matching-an-overloaded-function-to-its-polymorphic-argument)
It is stated that overload resolution is done at compile time. Your code would require overload resolution during execution time as it is not clear what type would be placed in the vector during compile time.

Comment: *This is quite an odd use of polymorphism* -- there is no polymorphism at all.

Comment: @Walter I was implying that the understanding of polymorphism is quite odd. Sorry for that. I however do understand the wish for an "polymorphic" object conversion.

Answer (score 0):

as long as you insert the object as struct_unit, you'll always get this kind of object back and your drawUnit function called will always be the one for struct_unit. Aren't you able to move the drawUnit() function inside the object and make a class ? If you make the function virtual, you can have the correct one called.

Comment: well it was my backup plan...since this is only part of code showed here and modifying ll be more complex

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're trying to do. There is a very slick way to do this, introduced in this video which I would recommend anyone to study.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil
[Inheritance Is The Base Class of Evil][1]

The basic premise here is that "inheritance should be an implementation detail, not an interface".

The more I have worked this way, the happier I have been that I have done so.